# Xamarin version of Android SDK packages are not found (both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

After an upgrade of Xamarin.Android solution I've encountered the following error:

> Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\24.2.1.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.

There are number of other android support packages mentioned too. I can reproduce exactly the same situation with Xamarin.Forms. 
I've checked the paths mentioned, but i can see the correct .jar in there. Forcing a reinstall of the NuGet package does not fix the problem.

Comment: This is documented here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Comment: @JonDouglas The documented case is related, but it is different. I've successfully updated the NuGet package, but later on build i've got the message above. Also the solution wouldn't work in my case, because the AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips folder content need to be deleted too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by broken downloaded archives or broken extracted archives content. The solution is:

1. Ensure you have the latest version of the packages via Android SDK
   Manager (e.g. Extras -> Android Support Library)
2. Delete the content of
   C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips
3. Delete the content of the corresponding to the error message
   C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.PACKAGE_NAME
   folders
4. Rebuild the solution from Visual Studio

NOTE: Do not interrupt rebuild process. It takes some time to download the archives. They are relatively big.